# Minimizing a hidden objective function

Tags: optimization, minimize

I am trying to minimize an objective function that is unknown/hidden. I have the feasibility of generating the output of the function f(x1,x2) based on the input parameters x1,x2. Other than that, I do not have visibility into the workings/internals of the objective function. Both the input variables have ranges of the order 0 <= x1,x2 < upper limit.

I was wondering what kind of ML methodology can be applied to get the minimum?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why does it need to be ML? There are some robust solutions, such as RANSAC and Nelder Mead, where you only need to plug in your objective function (https://octave.sourceforge.io/optim/function/nelder_mead_min.html) It's still possible, that the constraints need to be applied manually to the source code.

Comment: I did implement Nelder Mead, but for some reason, it is not finding optimal solutions